# Can't get ip address with wmic command for PPPoP interface

Tags: networking, netsh, wmic

I have tried to get ipv4 address of one of adapters, precisely from "PPPoP WAN Adapter" when it is connected, using wmic nic and wmic nicconfig commands but it didn't work. In general, when PPPoP is connected i can find the interface with wmic commands but wmic returns IPEnabled as FALSE, DHCP as FALSE, MAC as empty and there is no IP address to return.
Although i am able to get address using `netsh interface ip show` command, i am not very please with it - netsh has no where clause and I don't know how to limit result only to address field. Any suggestion? Maybe wmic is not working with pppop adapters?

Comment: Ok, i have found a solution here, `for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%G in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="PPPoP" ^| findstr "Adres IP" ^| findstr [0-9]')`. Still not sure why wmic command can't do the same though. How to close this thread?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this batch file can solve your problem or not ? just give a try and tell me the result on your side !

```
@echo off
Title Get NetconnectionID - MAC Address - IP Address 
@for /f "skip=2 delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4" %%L in (
    'wmic nic where "netenabled=true" get macaddress^,index^,netconnectionid^,productname /format:csv'
    ) do (
        @for /f "skip=2 delims={}, tokens=2" %%A in (
            'wmic nicconfig where "index=%%M" get ipaddress^,ipsubnet /format:csv'
        ) do (
            @echo %%L - %%O - %%N - %%A
            @echo %%L - %%O - %%N - %%A>"%~dpn0.txt"
        )
)
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
If exist "%~dpn0.txt" Start "" /MAX "%~dpn0.txt"
Exit /B
```

Comment: Nope. It is quite good base as example for other scripts but as I said earlier, it seems PPPoP can't be read with wmic command. It is listed but with empty fields.